# Netbeans change code coverage colors location in the UI

Tags: netbeans, ide, netbeans-8

I am using the [Darcula LAF plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/62424/darcula-laf-for-netbeans) in Netbeans for PHP. It looks really good, but there is a problem with the code coverage highlighting where the light green and red make the highlighted lines unreadable. I found [this](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=188452) bug filed on netbeans.org and its status is "RESOLVED FIXED". I have looked around the options in the UI and I cannot find where I can change these colors. Does such a place exist?

Here are the contents of my "About" dialog in Netbeans:

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 1
Java: 1.8.0_101; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.101-b13
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_101-b13
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)
User directory: C:\Users\<MyUser>\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2
Cache directory: C:\Users\<MyUser>\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2
```

Comment: Same here... Did you find a solution?

Comment: It's been a while but while looking for the same regarding Java: Did you check Fonts & Colors | Syntax | Language: PHP and looked for Category “Code Coverage - Covered” etc.? The changeset http://hg.netbeans.org/releases/rev/0f7491c42271 seems to hint at that.